# Updating a Pandas dataframe with new data whilst retaining existing ID number

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a Pandas dataframe that can be represented as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4],
                   'gp':['a','a','b','b'],
                   'meta':['one','two','three','four'],
                   'matchvar':['wwww','w ww w','xxxx','xyxx'],
                   'match':[np.nan,'yes',np.nan,'no']})
```

...which looks like:

```
   id gp   meta matchvar match
0   1  a    one     wwww   NaN
1   2  a    two   w ww w   yes
2   3  b  three     xxxx   NaN
3   4  b   four     xyxx    no
```

The data can be grouped on 'gp' column using groupby:

```
for g in df.groupby(['gp']):
    print(g[1])

   id gp meta matchvar match
0   1  a  one     wwww   NaN
1   2  a  two   w ww w   yes

   id gp   meta matchvar match
2   3  b  three     xxxx   NaN
3   4  b   four     xyxx    no
```

If the last row of data in a group contains 'yes' in the 'match' column, I want to retain the last row of data only BUT the 'id' column needs to be updated with the value from the preceding row.

If the last row of data in a group contains 'no' in the 'match' column then both rows need to be retained with no changes.

This can be summarised as:

```
   id gp meta matchvar match
0   1  a  one     wwww   NaN  --> [row discarded]
1   2  a  two   w ww w   yes  --> 1   1  a  two   w ww w   yes [N.B. id from previous row]
```

...and:

```
   id gp   meta matchvar match
2   3  b  three     xxxx   NaN  --> 2   3  b  three     xxxx   NaN
3   4  b   four     xyxx    no  --> 3   4  b   four     xyxx    no
```

Therefore, the expected output should be a dataframe with the following structure:

```
   id gp   meta matchvar match
1   1  a    two   w ww w   yes
2   3  b  three     xxxx   NaN
3   4  b   four     xyxx    no
```

I can retain the final row of a group using .last() but I can't work out how to maintain the 'id' value from the preceding row.

Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Comment: Do the `yes` and `no` values in `match` column only occur on the last rows?

Comment: Each group only contains a maximum of 2 rows and the last (or second) row contains the 'yes' and 'no' values.

Comment: is there any case a group having only one row?

Comment: Some groups could potentially have a single row but I could filter those out  beforehand if necessary.

Comment: in that case, just separate `yes` group from `no` group. Process `id` of `yes` to get the previous row value and `concat` them back. I posted a solution using this logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your logic and only using vectorized methods to keep our code efficient, we can do the following:

```
mask_yes = df['match'].eq('yes') # array with True for rows with 'yes'
mask_no = df['match'].eq('no')   # array with True for rows with 'no'

# if the row is 'yes', get the shifted id, else the original id
df['id'] = np.where(mask_yes, df['id'].shift(), df['id']) 

# if a group has 'no' mark all rows as True so we can keep the whole group
mask = df.assign(indicator=mask_no).groupby('gp')['indicator'].transform('any')
# filter on groups with 'no' or only the row 'yes'
df = df[mask | mask_yes]
```

```
    id gp   meta matchvar match
1  1.0  a    two   w ww w   yes
2  3.0  b  three     xxxx   NaN
3  4.0  b   four     xyxx    no
```

Answer (score 1):

As you confirm in the comment that every group has 2 rows, so you may try the following logic:  *create mask `m` to separate 'no' group from 'yes' group. Process `id` of 'yes' group and pick its last rows by using `drop_duplicates` and `concat` them together*

```
m = df.match.eq('no').groupby(df.gp).transform('any')
df_yes = (df.assign(id=df.id.shift(fill_value=0))[~m]
            .drop_duplicates('gp', keep='last'))
df_final = pd.concat([df_yes, df[m]])

Out[108]:
   id gp   meta matchvar match
1   1  a    two   w ww w   yes
2   3  b  three     xxxx   NaN
3   4  b   four     xyxx    no
```